# Can the MasterPage be designated from the Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I have a couple different userTypes (Admin, User) and a MasterPage for each. I am beginning to create some Views that will be used by both userTypes where i would like to assign the MasterPage programmaticly (based on _currentUser).

Possible?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Controller.View() overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470743.aspx)

```
return View("MyView", "MyMaster");
```

in your controller to determine the view and the master page it should use.

```
public ViewResult Index() {
  if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) {
    return View("Index", "AdminMaster");
  }
  else {
    return View("Index", "DefaultMaster");
  }
}
```